# Poor Quality Audio on Logitech USB Headset But the Left & Right sound test is fine

Tags: sound, usb, logitech

As the title says, I got logitech USB headset, the test audio is fine, but when I am watching youtube or playing games the sound is terrible, the sounds comes out but its very bad & I cant hear any speech.

I've tried tuning alsamixer but to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

edit : I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and streaming using firefox, I've tested other browsers and the result is the same.

The game that I've tested is Dota 2.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the heads up, I've provided the info that you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution from this [post](https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2020/11/25/problem-with-logitech-usb-headset-cant-hear-voice/)

> The solution was as simple (and ridiculous!) as just changing left-right balance from the default, neutral position.